# Plotting a signal along with its harmonics in one figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would appreciate it if someone could help me plot a figure similar to the following picture. I want to draw the fundamental signal along with a few first harmonics using `pgfplots`.

[image]

Comment: There is a question which does this. I am unable to find it right now.

Comment: Oops I always forget that gold badge thing